# Adding two created_at on one insert

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I want to add another created_at column on the database columns for reference.

I want to have a created_at and created_at1 at the same time.

This is what I have in my Model:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'created_at1';

protected $dates = [created_at, created_at1];
```

But I'm receiving this error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value.

Comment: if You want To Display the Created at date in the Different Format You can Can Format and Appends to Model

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add casting to the created_at since Laravel has already done it for you.

You need to add inside the string like

```
protected $dates = ['created_at1']
```

If you want to set the created_at1 when a new model is created, you can add [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events).

Inside your model,

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($model){
        $model->created_at1 = Carbon::now();
    });
}
```

Inside controller

```
$model = Model::create([
    ...
    ]);
```

Now it will set created_at and created_at1

For the insert, you have to manually save the value to the created_at1 because it will not reflect the model event.

```
Model::insert([
    ...
    'created_at1' => Carbon::now()
]);
```

Comment: How will laravel detect if created_at1 is a date on when the row is inserted?

Comment: Yes. For that, you can make the column to datetime in your Schema migration. And using of casting like above answer. You were having a syntax error.

Comment: I've already a created_date1, but after removing the casting only created_at is filled with dates.

Comment: Did you remove casting for both created_at and created_at1 ? Or removed only for created_at?

Comment: I only remove the created at. Can you give me some code on what do you mean? :D

Comment: From my understanding, you wanted the created_at1 value to be of datetime type. It can be done by casting. You need created_at1 to be set when create?

Comment: By default laravel automatically filing the created_at when you insert a data, what I want is to use that function and also add the date on created_at1 or created_at2. I thought adding const CREATED_AT will fix my problem but it doesn't. And yes ofcouse create_dateXXX is a datetime.

Comment: Nice idea. But what I want is a created_at1 upon insertion of data. For example I've added a new record, not on model creation.

Comment: Updated the answer for the insert.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be passing value to `created_at` column while inserting data. Please do check. If this is not the case please do provide more information on your problem.